# What is the runtime complexity of isPrime(n) if you iterate up to sqrt(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, primes

What would the Big O for the following method?

```
boolean isPrime( num )
    i = 2
    while  i <= sqrt(num)
        if num % i == 0
            return false
        i += 1
    return true
```

My thought is `O(sqrt(n))`, which isn't a typical answer.

Below are a couple of tables to clarify my reasoning:

In this table, every time N is quadrupled, the number of iterations only doubles.

| N | iterations = sqrt(N) |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 16 | 4 |
| 64 | 8 |
| 256 | 16 |
| 1024 | 32 |

To contrast this behavior with a linear function,
if we looped **while i <= num/2** instead, the table would be:

| N | iterations = N/2 |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 16 | 8 |
| 64 | 32 |
| 256 | 128 |
| 1024 | 512 |

Now every time N is quadrupled, the number of iterations also quadruples.
I.e. the runtime varies directly with N.

Comment: As long as `%` is considered constant-time, the overall algorithm is in fact `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: Of course if `num` is even, then your loop runs a constant number of 1 (one) iteration. See "best case", "worst case", "on average". The next question to consider is the complexity of running `isPrime(n)` for *every `n`* from 2 to `num`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - checking up to *√n* gives you a much better complexity. And if you define *num = n* and assume the modulo operator is constant time, then your time complexity is correct.

The reason this is not a 'typical answer', as you state, is that typically we measure time complexity on the *size* of the input. To encode *num* in binary, we need *log<sub>2</sub>(num)* bits (and similarly with any other nontrivial base) so the actual input size is *n = log<sub>2</sub>(num)*.

If we define *n* this way, then you will find that *num = O(2<sup>n</sup>)*, so your overall time complexity becomes *O(√(2<sup>n</sup>))* or *O(2<sup>0.5n</sup>*).

However, this is not more correct than your expression, it is just a more common (and more useful) way to express it, and it might clarify why your answer doesn't seem typical when you search.

Ultimately what matters is that you define your *n*. If you don't, it is probably assumed by the reader that it's the logarithm of `num` and they might think you falsely claim your algorithm is the fastest in the world.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question of what `n` is in this algorithm. My assumption was that `n = num` as you said, and I hadn't considered other possibilities.

Comment: @jazz2e10 Glad to be of help. Please consider marking the answer as accepted, if you found it helpful.